# Where to find a detailed catalog of installed packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

In my 12.04 installation I've just discovered a whole lot of nice packages that I knew nothing about (or had forgotten).
So - is there a facility that makes a catalog of all expressly installed packages, complete with a description of each package?
I couldnt find any such facility. So I had to do all the grunt work myself **.

Richard H

**What I did:

- First, «*$ aptitude search '~i!~M'*» made a list of expressly installed packages.  Thank You for this to [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)
- Then a Perl script did «*$ apt-cache show (name of package)*»  to "search and generate interesting output from the package metadata" for each package.
- A second Perl script added information from all the README files in /usr/share/doc/
- And third Perl script used Asciidoctor to format the results as an html file, *A for accountsservice* to *Z for Zenity*, complete with individual descriptions and links for each package.

My experience suggests that it would be nice if Ubuntu had a single facility that did all this, so as to offer all users such a catalog by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't Synaptic > Status > Installed the answer to what you are looking for?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and yes, *Synaptic > Status > Installed*  is ± exactly what I was looking for.
Its perhaps not as easy to browse as my html files, but everything is there, its quick, and it works out-of-the-box.